# VS 2010 Intellisense WebAPI Webforms

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-web-api

I have added WebApi nuget package and a few api controllers to an existing Webforms project, however intellisense isn't working on any of the controllers and I can't use F12 to go to a definition.

CodeRush is working fine and I have ran Devenv /resetuserdata in case it was a VS thing but I suspect it is to do with WebAPI code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Intellisense & Go to Definition are working perfectly fine here with Web API RC and ReSharper. Try adding the packages to an empty Web project via NuGet and see if it works that way. If not, there is a problem with your installation (or CodeRush for that matter).

Comment: I will try an empty project, it's fine in MVC projects so it could be a Webforms or existing project problem.